# C++ Comparing Array Values in Lottery Game

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

I'm making a lottery program and I'm trying to make a function to check how many of the user's numbers are the same as the winning numbers and write out the different rewards for having the same numbers. The code compiles just fine. I am just having the issue of creating the function and what to do in it.

Basically,  check to see if they have won any prizes in the Lotto game.  Check each number in the UserTicket array to see if that number is in the WinningNums array and count how many numbers are matched.

Display:  JACKPOT - 1 MILLION if all 7 numbers were correct
Display:  GREAT! - $100,000 if 6 numbers were correct
Display:  LUCKY YOU! - $5,000 if 5 numbers were correct
Display:  NOT BAD - $100 if 4 numbers were correct
Display:  FREE TICKET if 3 numbers were correct
Display:  SORRY NOTHING if 2 or fewer numbers were correct

I have been having trouble with this and I am new to C++ and I have been only coding for a few months. Help would be GREATLY appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size);
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size);
void checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size);

int main()
{
    const int size = 7;
    int UserTicket[size];
    int WinningNums[size];
    char selection;
    string name;

    do
    {
        cout << "LITTLETON CITY LOTTO MODEL: " << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Play Lotto" << endl;
        cout << "q) Quit Program" << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection : " << endl;
        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == '1')
        {
            cout << "Please enter your name: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, name);

            getLottoPicks(UserTicket, size);
            genWinNums(WinningNums, size);
            checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size);

            cout << name << "'s LOTTO RESULTS" << endl;
            cout << "----------------------" << endl;
            cout << "WINNING TICKET NUMBERS : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
            cout << WinningNums[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
            cout << name << "'s TICKET       : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                cout << UserTicket[i] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;

        }
        else if (selection == 'q')
        {
            cout << "You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for 
            using!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection. Please try again." << endl;
        }

    } while (selection != 'q');

    return 0;
}
void getLottoPicks(int userNums[], int size)
{
    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int input;
        cout << "selection #" << times + 1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> input;

        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            if (userNums[i] == input)
            {
                 isNotDuplicate = false;
            }
        }
        if (isNotDuplicate == true)
        {
             userNums[times] = input;
        }
        else
        {
             cout << "You already picked this number. Please enter a different number: " <<
             endl;
             times--;
        }
     }

}
void genWinNums(int winNums[], int size)
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    for (int times = 0; times < size; times++)
    {
        int i;
        bool isNotDuplicate = true;
        while (isNotDuplicate)
        {
            isNotDuplicate = false;
            i = 1 + rand() % 40;
            for (int j = 0; j < times; j++)
            {
                if (i == winNums[j])
                {
                    isNotDuplicate = true;
                }
            }  
        }
        winNums[times] = i;
    }
}
void checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size)
{

}
```

Comment: What trouble have you been having?  Does it not compile?  If so, please include the error messages in your post.  Does the logic not work correctly?  If so please detail what it should be, and what you are getting.

Comment: Tactical note: Don't `ignore` BEFORE a read just in case there is garbage you want removed from the stream before reading. Place the `ignore` AFTER the read that left the garbage in the stream to clear out the garbage. Why? 1) it keeps the cause and effect close to one another, and that helps significantly when reading code. 2) When you `ignore` before it is only a matter of time before you reach the `ignore` without any data you need `ignore`ed and wind up `ignore`ing data that you need.

Comment: What do you want `void checkNums(int[], int[], int)` to do? Currently there is no way of any data to be extracted from it. If you want to check whether the `size`th value it true recursively you can return `bool`. If you want to return how many values match you need a return type of `int` or similar.

Comment: If you want to simplify this a bit, use sets. 2 things about your coding syle thoug: use consistent intendation;This makes the code easier to read. Furthermore any statement continued from a pervious line should have a greater intendation than the line starting the statement; I'm referring to the last `cout << ... << endl;` in `getLottoPicks` here; the line `endl;` can easily be seen as it's own statement, if you're not looking carefully which could be avoided by putting `<<` on this line and adding some intendation.

Comment: In `main`, the line `checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size);` is not the way to *call* a function. And since there are several examples of calling them properly (one on the preceding line, in fact), that should be apparent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should do 2 loops, like this:

```
int checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size)
{
    int nums = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            if(userNums[i] == winNums[j])
                nums++;
     
    return nums;
}
```

This function will return how many numbers are correct
and this works if you don't care about the order and you're sure that no number can be in the same array 2 times.
If you want to check the order as well:

```
int checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size)
{
    int nums = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if(userNums[i] == winNums[i])
            nums++;
     
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: And then (in the main) you can write `int nums = checkNums(int userNums[], int winNums[], int size)` and you can check `if(nums == size)'

Comment: That is not valid code for calling `checkNums`. Also this should not be a comment

Comment: Should be called like `checkNums(UserTicket, WinningNums, size)` instead. But note that `checkNums()` only tells HOW MANY users won, not WHICH USERS won.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah it should be `int nums  = checkNums(UserTicket, WinningNums, size)` and then `if(nums == size)`. The function tells how many numbers the user got right and there's only 1 user

Comment: @JonathanFin "*The function tells how many numbers the user got right and there's only 1 user*" - good point, I misread what the code is doing.